# Setting a value in Frappe application isn't reflected in ERPNext GUI

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I have added a 'number_of_members' value to the Customer DocType via customization.

In my application I have tried several ways to update the value. However the value never updates in the webpage. I feel like I'm missing some sort of save or update or commit step.

For example I have tried:

- `frappe.client.set_value('Customer', '00042', 'number_of_members', 8887)`
- `frappe.set_value('Customer', '00042', 'number_of_members', 8887)`
- `frappe.db.set_value('Customer', '00042', 'number_of_members', 8887)`
- and also

```
customer = frappe.get_doc('Customer', '00042')
customer.number_of_members = 8887
customer.save()
```

In each case I can do something like frappe.get_value, or frappe.get_doc and it shows the value is set to 8887. However it never updates in the web side. This is what makes me think I'm updating some sort of cache or database transaction and I need some way to save it, but have not had any luck.

I am mostly testing this via `bench console` if that has any bearing on it, but I've tried a couple of the methods in my application code as well.

Relevant documentation:

- [Frappe Developer API - Document](https://frappe.io/docs/user/en/api/document#docsave)
- [Frappe Developer API - Database](https://frappe.io/docs/user/en/api/database#frappedbset_value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the answer is to call `frappe.db.commit()` after making changes. If someone can point this out in the documentation so I can better understand how I'm missing stuff, I would appreciate it.

I also noticed if you try to Save something in the UI before you send `frappe.db.commit()` the UI will hang.

Comment: Hi @laydros. Im need to update also the GUI. calling frappe.db.commit() doest not show. can you share a piece of your code please